# different resolutions and camera_info_manager/openni (e.g. kinect camera)

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, camera-info-manager, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After the calibration and using the camera_calibration_parsers, I get a rgb_A00363A22671047A.yaml file. This file can be placed in /home/username/.ros/camera_info/.
But I can chance the resolution anytime(e.g. 640x480 -> 1280x1024).
How is it possible to store different calibrations, one for every supported resolution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12701/different-resolutions-and-camera_info_manager/openni-(e.g.-kinect-camera)/) by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1480 on 2012-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle you shouldn't have to store different calibrations for each resolution. Going from 640x480 to 1280x1024 amounts to changing the binning and region-of-interest settings on the camera, which don't affect its intrinsic calibration. See [REP 104](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html) for the gory details.

It's possible that the OpenNI driver doesn't update camera_info correctly when you change the resolution - it's supposed to, but we haven't tested it much. If so, please [report a bug](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect#Report_a_Bug).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2